# Weird walkie-talkie interference with Logitech unifying receiver

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, logitech

This is insanely weird, and although it's not necessarily a problem, I'm really curious what's going on here.

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 and have a wireless Logitech keyboard and mouse along with the Logitech unifying receiver. I'm running [Solaar](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Logitech_Unifying_Receiver) to help manage those. I work for a company that provides a [MURS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-Use_Radio_Service) [walkie-talkie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walkie-talkie) for work onsite.

This evening, I was playing around and turned the walkie-talkie on and tapped the talk button. My screen went nuts. The application that was open closed, and a string of random text appeared in a background application. I'm not too knowledgeable with wireless technologies, but it seems really strange that my walkie-talkie can cause interference and interact with my PC. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 7):

RFI (Radio Frequency Interference) is actually common. For example from [this article](https://www.cnet.com/tech/computing/walkie-talkie-interference-with-macs-apple-displays/):

> "The walkie-talkies in the article yesterday are Motorola FRS (Family
> Radio Service) transceivers and operate in the 400Mhz range (around
> 460mhz). At these frequencies the wiring in computers and TV sets can
> act as antennas. The higher the frequency the short an antenna has to
> be to be resonant. Depending on the power level of the transmission
> this can cause all kinds of problem with frequency dependent devices -
> such as monitors, mice, keyboards and the like.
>
> "The frequencies of the two devices can mix and cause problems by
> adding to or subtracting from the frequencies the device is expecting.
> This could cause the screen to distort and could also lead to false
> mouse movements and clicks and well as false keyboard entries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a similar setup at work (although using Windows, not Linux) and I can't remember anything like this happening before. I'll be bringing my keyboard and receiver to test tomorrow. This seems like a potential vulnerability, being able to arbitrarily interact with a computer without any sort of pairing or direct access to the machine.

Comment: Interference don't surprise me... But I would have thought that there would be a minimal security with the unifying receiver (logitech are soo common, we shouldn't be able to communicate without pairing). BUT maybe there is a encryption with windows that you don't get with Linux/Solaar

Comment: @sayanel no, it doesn't work that way. The encryption isn't a software feature :) But the packet integrity isn't very strong, just a CRC16 (I *think*; the chip also supports CRC8 and no CRC, which would be even weaker), so if you get it to decode a continuous stream of noise, some of it is bound to appear as valid packets. The encryption just means that you can't control their content.